# ViewModel doesn't bind to View MvvmCross

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross

I have the following problem:

in the application, when the user returns to the computer, I have to process the event and show him a modal window in which to offer 3 possible answers.

I do this using the service:

```
public WinUserReturnDialogServiceImpl(ISettingsManager 
settingsManager) : base(settingsManager)
{
    _dialogPage = new UserReturnDialogPage();
    _dialogPage.AddButton.Click += OnAddButtonClick;
    _dialogPage.DivideButton.Click += OnDivideButtonClick;
    _dialogPage.CancelButton.Click += OnCancelButtonClick;

    _dialogWindow = new DialogWindow()
    {
        Content = _dialogPage
    };
}

protected override void ShowCustomDialog(UserReturnDialogData dialogData)
        {

                 _pauseDuration = Math.Floor(dialogData._userAfkMinuites);
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    _dialogPage.AFKMessage.Text = string.Format("Вы отсутствовали {0} мин", _pauseDuration);
                    _dialogWindow.Show();
                });
            return;
        }

private void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseCustomDialog();
    }
```

Page Code behind:

```
//[MvxViewFor(typeof(UserReturnDialogViewModel))]
//[WinContentPresentation(IsSheet = true, TransitionForwardType = TransitionType.ToRight, TransitionReturnType = TransitionType.FromRigth, WindowIdentifier = nameof(DialogWindow))]
[MvxContentPresentation(WindowIdentifier = nameof(DialogWindow), StackNavigation = false)]
public partial class UserReturnDialogPage : MvxWpfView<UserReturnDialogViewModel>
{

    public UserReturnDialogPage() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

and page xaml:

```
<views:MvxWpfView
x:Class="SmlHours.Win.Presentation.Views.Pages.Dialogs.UserReturnDialogPage"
x:TypeArguments="vm:UserReturnDialogViewModel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SmlHours.Core.Presentation.ViewModels.Dialogs;assembly=SmlHours.Core"
...
<Button
x:Name="AddButton"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Visibility="Visible"
Width="85"
Height="32"
Template="{DynamicResource BaseNavigationButtonTemplate}"
Command="{Binding AddTimeAfterUserReturn}"
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UserReturnDialogViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private IMonitoringInteractor _monitoringInteractor;

        public IMvxCommand AddTimeAfterUserReturn { get; private set; }

        public UserReturnDialogViewModel(IMonitoringInteractor monitoringInteractor)
        {
            _monitoringInteractor = monitoringInteractor;
            AddTimeAfterUserReturn = CreateAsyncCommand(AddTimeAfterReturnTask);
        }

        //I need to fire this command after button pressed!!!
        private Task AddTimeAfterReturnTask() => Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var model = _monitoringInteractor.FixationTimeAfterUserReturn();
        });
    }
```

The event is triggered, the page is displayed, but the viewmodel is not attached to the page and does not respond to button presses. However, the OnAddButtonClick, etc. service commands that close the window react to pressing the buttons.
How do I bind view and viewmodel, so that pressing the buttons works in the viewmodel?
Thanks a lot to those who responded

Comment: did you set your datacontext anywhere?

Comment: if you mean DataContext="UserReturnDialogViewModel" in XAML -Yes, i try to set it, i see this param in debug, bun have no binding vm and v(((

Comment: in your debugger can you see an instance of your UserReturnDialogViewModel-Class beeing created by the View?

Comment: _dialogPage = new UserReturnDialogPage();_dialogPage.ViewModel - null So, I think vm isn't created by the view

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I try to  create new Window/Page by manual. For binding vm and view should use ViewDispatcher:

```
 var ViewDispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>();
 ViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel(newMvxViewModelRequest(typeof(UserReturnDialogViewModel)));
```